# How can I access the PayTime field which is inside 'paid' class in Linq

Tags: c#, linq, design-patterns

There is a field called `FactorStateBase` which we implemented using pattern strategy. This field has a default value of `PendingFactorState`. We wish to access all factors that in paid state and their dates fall within a specific time interval. This payment time interval is 'new'ed inside the `PaidFactorState` when the payment is actually done and the new class is assigned to the state field.

My question is how can I access the payment date field which is inside 'paid' class in Linq?

Thank you,

```
   public class Factor : AggregateRoot<long>, IHasCreationTime
{

    public Factor(long id, long orderId, decimal price)
    {
        Id = id;
        Price = price;
        OrderId = orderId;
       FactorStateBase = new PendingFactorState(Guid.NewGuid());
    }
    public long OrderId { get; private set; }
    public decimal Price { get; private set; }
    public virtual FactorStateBase FactorStateBase { get; private set; }
    public void PayFactor(Guid id, string messageNumber, Guid paymentId, string transactionCode)
    {
      FactorStateBase = new PaidFactorState(id, messageNumber, paymentId, transactionCode);
    }

}
public abstract class FactorStateBase : Entity
{
    protected FactorStateBase(Guid id)
    {
        Id = id;
    }
}
public class PaidFactorState : FactorStateBase
{
    public PaidFactorState(Guid id, string messageNumber, Guid paymentId, string transactionCode) : base(id)
    {
        PayTime = DateTime.Now;
        MessageNumber = messageNumber;
        PaymentId = paymentId;
        TransactionCode = transactionCode;
    }
    public DateTime PayTime { get; private set; }
    public string MessageNumber { get; private set; }
    public Guid PaymentId { get; private set; }
    public string TransactionCode { get; private set; }

}
```

Comment: And where is your `Paid` class?

Comment: Please be aware that we are not going to hack your computer in order to be able to see what you see. As Daniel pointed out, we can not give you any answer with so little code (we do not know what type `FactorStateBase` is, and we do not have any class definition). Could you provide a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: @ Daniel DirtyNative Martin

  public class PaidFactorState : FactorStateBase
    {
        public PaidFactorState(Guid id, string messageNumber, Guid paymentId, string transactionCode) : base(id)
        {
            PayTime = DateTime.Now;
            MessageNumber = messageNumber;
            PaymentId = paymentId;
            TransactionCode = transactionCode;
        }
}

Comment: Even if the `Paid` class was provided we have no clue what's the relation of that class to the code shown above. The question is very unclear.

Comment: @ John Ephraim Tugado
I want access PayTime for example
var factors=_repository.AsQueryable.Where(p=>p.FactorStateBase  is PaidFactorState) and within a specific time interval

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
factors=_repository.AsQueryable.Where(p=>p.FactorStateBase is PaidFactorState && p.PayDate > = yourdate)
```

you can use `is` for this code and for paid filed you use PendingFactorState field